# Trying to print asterisk in bash but getting an error

Tags: bash

```
if [ $opt = "*" ]
then
    awk -v a="$num1" -v b="$num2" 'BEGIN {printf  "%.2f * %.2f = %.2f  \n",a,b, a*b}'
fi
```

I'm trying to check if the user entered * but I get an error because * refers to all files in the directory I tried and haven't found a solution 
can someone help me with this ?

Comment: Double-quote all variable references: `if [ "$opt" = "*" ]`. [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) is good at spotting problems like this.

Comment: See also [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells)